# Как удалить слайд из Google Презентации скриптом Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-script

Второй день сижу рою документацию по GAS, и не могу найти метод, чтобы удалить слайд из презентации.

```
let file = SlidesApp.openById(id);

  // Получаем слайды из файла
  slides = file.getSlides();

  slides[0].remove();
```

remove() - В документации про этот метод написано, что он удаляет страницу. Вопрос: А страница и слайд в Презентациях Гугла, это не одно и то же? Судя по тому, что этот метод не работает для удаления слайда, это разные вещи.

Кто может дать пояснения на этот счет? Чем страница отличается от слайда, и как удалить слайд из презентации?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня все работает. Предоставьте полную функцию.

```
function deleteFirstSlide() {
  const presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  
  const slides = presentation.getSlides();
  const firstSlide = slides[0];
  
  firstSlide.remove();
}
```